# calling a function from another script?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

**Problem**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ci/js/global_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ci/js/global.js"></script>
```

Why can't global.js find a function that I created in global_functions.js; right now I am only able to access that function use `window.helper = { func: function() {} }`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function id( input_id ) {
        return document.getElementById( input_id ); //global_functions.js
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(id( 'home_login' )).css( 'display', 'none' ); //global.js
}
```

Comment: may be your function is not define in global scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you are defining the function in a non-global scope. It is hard to say for sure though as you haven't shown us the code.

---

Update now that code has been added:

That is what is happening.

```
function() {                    // This is a function
    function id( input_id ) {   // So this function is scoped to it
        return document.getElementById( input_id );
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but the are both in a `document.ready()` function and I was under the impression that they all fired at the same time.

Comment: They fire sequentially, but the problem is one of *scope* not *timing*. If a function is defined inside an anonymous function that you pass to `ready()` then that function is only available within the scope of the anonymous function.

Comment: Do you mean you declared the functions **inside** document ready? as in `$(document).ready(function() { /* declare function x here */ });`? or do you mean that you called the functions inside document ready `$(document).ready(function() { /* call function x here */ });`?

Comment: it's not an anonymous function, check, I updated the question with some code.

Comment: @Phil — So your code doesn't start out with `$(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: @Quentin, oops, sorry, yes it is. Fixed.

Comment: Ah, I 100% knew it was a scoping problem, I just didn't think of the fact that it was already in an anonymous function with `ready()`. Thank you